# How to stub Mailer delivery in RSPEC

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, actionmailer

I want to stub sending email and return sample email result for further process.

Given I have:

```
message = GenericMailer.send_notification(id).deliver!
```

I want to do something like:

```
allow(GenericMailer).to receive_message_chain(:send_notification, :deliver)
   .and_return(mail_result_no_idea_what_is_like)
```

but above function obviously fails, `GenericMailer does not implement: deliver` or deliver! as tried.

I want to return some data as i need to test something like (and more):

```
message.header.select{|h| h.name == "Date"}.try(:first).try(:value).try(:to_datetime).try(:utc)
```

Comment: Change `:deliver` to `:deliver!`?

Comment: @CaTs i tried that before but same error as above.

Comment: do you want to return the contents of the email?

Comment: @Anthony yes :)

Answer (score 7):

`GenericMailer.send_notification` is returning an object of class `ActionMailer::MessageDelivery`

Example with `rails 5.1.4` and rspec `3.6.0`

```
it 'delivers notification' do
  copy = double()
  expect(GenericMailer).to receive(:send_notification).and_return(copy)
  expect(copy).to receive(:deliver!) # You can use allow instead of expect
  GenericMailer.send_notification.deliver!
end
```

Comment: for rails >5.2.x use `deliver_now!` instead of `deliver!`

Answer (score 1):

Finally came up with a solution. Thanks to @LolWalid info.

```
copy = double()
# recursive_ostruct_even_array is my method to convert hash/array to OpenStruct Obje
message = recursive_ostruct_even_array({
                                         "header" => [{"name" => "Date", "value" => Time.now.utc}],
                                         "to" => ["test@gmail.com"],
                                         "from" => ["from@gmail.com"],
                                         "subject" => "For Testing",
                                         "body" => "-"
                                       })
allow(GenericMailer).to receive(:send_notification).and_return(copy)
allow(copy).to receive(:deliver!).and_return(message)
```